# Generating a PDF as attachment in a mail in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, pdfkit, wicked-pdf, shrimp

**The problem**

I want to send emails with an invoice PDF attached to it.

I already have a invoice show view, with styling and javascript.

The javascript is making calculations for the total field, formatting the currency and dates and splitting at page breaks.

The show view is presenting the invoice just like it should be on the pdf.

**Attempts**

1. I have tried [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) and [pdfkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit). The problem is that
   when doing this..

   ```
   html = render_to_string(:action => "../invoices/show_pdf.html.erb") 
   mail(:to => @registration.billing_email, :subject => "Faktura") do |format|
     format.pdf do
       attachments['faktura.pdf'] = PDFKit.new(html).to_pdf
     end
   ```

   ..I don't have a browser to interpreter the javascript. So all
   calculations and formats is gone. When I open the pdf in the browser it's correct.
2. I also tried [shrimp](https://github.com/adeven/shrimp) which uses phantomjs to generate the
   PDF's. The problem with this solution is that I am using devise and
   the phantomjs browser has to be signed in in some way.

I need some suggestions on a elegant solution for this problem.

Either

Some way to render the view with all the javascript before I generate the PDF with pdfkit or wicked_pdf

or

How to assign a session cookie to phantomjs?

I am aware that this is two questions, but as it solves one problem I hope it is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `shrimp` would be your best bet. Since you need your javascript to be executed a solution that runs `PhantomJS` is probably the only way you can go.

Shrimp provides an easy way to add your session cookie in the request. Just to something like the following:

```
Shrimp::Phantom.new(url, options, {user_session: "a session"})
```

As you can understand the [initializer](https://github.com/adeven/shrimp/blob/master/lib/shrimp/phantom.rb) accepts an options hash and after that a hash with your cookies and their values.

Now the hard part would be to always have a valid session at your server to do the requests. Depending on your session management (e.g. you might have auto expiration) this could be a bit tricky.

---

**EDIT:** Adding Andreas's findings about how to hack user session in an Rails application using Devise based on a relevant [blog post](http://big-elephants.com/2012-12/pdf-rendering-with-phantomjs/) by the Shrimp creators:

*lib/devise/sign_in_interceptor.rb*

```
module Devise
  class SignInInterceptor
    def initialize(app, opts)
      @app    = app
      @scope  =opts[:scope]
      @secret = opts[:secret]
      @klass  = opts[:klass]
    end

    def call(env)
      if user = Rack::Request.new(env).cookies[@secret]
        env['warden'].session_serializer.store(@klass.constantize.find(user), @scope)
      end

      @app.call(env)
    end
  end
end
```

*config/application.rb*

```
require File.expand_path('../../lib/devise/sign_in_interceptor', __FILE__)
config.middleware.use Devise::SignInInterceptor, { :scope  => :user, :klass => 'User',
                                                    :secret => "our_very_very_long_secret" }
```

With this setup we can add a to_pdf method to our resource
*invoice.rb*

```
def to_pdf
  host        = Rails.env.production? ? 'www.adjust.io' : 'localhost:3000'
  url         = Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.reports_url(self, :host => host)
  cookie      = { 'our_very_very_long_secret' => user_id } #user_id is a instance method on the invoice class 
  options     = { :margin => "1cm"}
  res         = Shrimp::Phantom.new(url, options, cookie).to_pdf("#{Rails.root}/invoices/invoice_#{self.id}.pdf")
end
```

Comment: I tried to edit you answer to incorporate my answer, but the edit was rejected because "This edit changes too much in the original post; the original meaning or intent of the post would be lost."  For future reference, I really don't like two answers when we just need one. Edit in my answer in yours and I'll accept yours.

Comment: I added your findings above. However the blog link seems to return 404. I hope it's only termporal.

Comment: It was incorrect. I've fixed it, but still 404, maybe the site is down for some reason. Let's keep the link for a few days